# Help with translation of こともあって

Tags: grammar

I'm playing through Phantasy Star right now, and there's a scene where mercenaries are hired to gather in some ruins for treasure. One says:

「場所が場所って**こともあって**腕利きを集めているのかもな。」

Supposedly, this translates along the lines of "A place like this is bound to draw the best."

I'm not sure how accurate that translation is, as the company who translated the game is not known for having the "best" translations.

I understand 「腕利きを集めているのかもな。」which translates to "gathering the able/skilled" (with doubt), but I'm unable to understand the grammatical structure of the first part, mainly こともあって and the recurring 「場所」.

My guess is that the first part is supposed to emphasize the current location.

Comment: こともあって roughly corresponds to "what with," "among other reasons." It explains that something is one of the (possible) reasons. And 場所が場所 reads "the very location itself."

Answer (score 1):

日本語は、想像できる部分を省略する事が多いので、訳しにくいのだと思います。

今回の例文の最初の部分を元に戻すと
「(これから行きたい)場所が、(危ないと予想される)場所ということもあって」
になると思います。

「ってこともあって」は、「ということもあって」の、少し　くだけた表現です。
「他にも、色々起こると思う」という意味が隠されています。

「のかもな」は、「腕利きを集めている」理由に対して使われています。

省略されている部分を補足すると、
「(他の理由かもしれないけれど、)　危ない場所に行くから、腕利きを集めているのでは?」
という感じになると思います。

---

I think your translation is correct.

(with doubt) is for "reason for gathering skilled".

Two 「場所」 has different meanings.
First 「場所」 means "The place they want to go"
Second one is "maybe a place with danger"

「こともあって」is "There may be another reason, but..."